# image assets error in rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm using Rails 3.1, trying to link to an image in one of my views by doing this:

```
<%= image_tag "logo.png" %>
```

I've placed 'logo.png' in the folder '/app/assets/images'.

The view renders the image as '/assets/logo.png', however the image is broken, with this error when opened in a new window:
"No route matches [GET] "/assets/logo.png""

Any advice for me?

I'm running in development mode, with the following config:

```
config.cache_classes = false
config.whiny_nils = true
config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
config.active_support.deprecation = :log
config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin
config.assets.compress = false
config.assets.debug = true
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Try with `asset_tag`.</strike>

But I thought that `"/assets/logo.png"` was the correct path for the image, so I'm not sure what's wrong.

When your browse to `localhost:xxxx/assets/logo.png`, you get a 404 or the image?

Comment: i get - No route matches [GET] "/assets/logo.png"

Comment: Cool :) It had to be something like that, it didnt make sense that the image wasn't accessible at this url.

Answer (score -1):

try this : <%= image_tag "assets/logo.png" %> if it won't work then try
'rake assets:precompile' in the rails project directory, it may work...